# Stop my countdown timer from refreshing when I reload my page

Tags: javascript

Each time I refresh my page, the timer resets. I'd like it to continue from where it left off with until it hits 0.

My JS where the timer is handled:

```js
var target_date = new Date().getTime() + (1000*3600*48); // set the countdown date
var days, hours, minutes, seconds; // variables for time units

var countdown = document.getElementById("tiles"); // get tag element

getCountdown();

setInterval(function () { getCountdown(); }, 1000);

function getCountdown(){

 // find the amount of "seconds" between now and target
 var current_date = new Date().getTime();
 var seconds_left = (target_date - current_date) / 1000;

 days = pad( parseInt(seconds_left / 86400) );
 seconds_left = seconds_left % 86400;
   
 hours = pad( parseInt(seconds_left / 3600) );
 seconds_left = seconds_left % 3600;
    
 minutes = pad( parseInt(seconds_left / 60) );
 seconds = pad( parseInt( seconds_left % 60 ) );

 // format countdown string + set tag value
 countdown.innerHTML = "<span>" + days + "</span><span>" + hours + "</span><span>" + minutes + "</span><span>" + seconds + "</span>"; 
}

function pad(n) {
 return (n < 10 ? '0' : '') + n;
}
```

```html
<div id="tiles"></div>
```

Help appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Would [`localStorage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage) work for you?

```
var persisted = Number(localStorage.getItem('target_date')),
    target_date;

if(persisted > 0){
    target_date = persisted;
} else {
    target_date = Date.now() + (1000 * 3600 * 48);
    localStorage.setItem('target_date', target_date);
}
```

[**» Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/k2vLx69f/1/)